# How should I install roof clips for heat tape on architectural shingles?

Tags: roof

I installed roof clips for heat tape to my shingles (architectural/dimensional) and I now second guess myself. Directions said to put the clip in the doubled up area of the shingle without specifying further. I did as such but I did it under the top layer of the doubled up area. To do so, I had to use a putty knife and light hammering to break down adhesive to be able to put my clip in. See picture.

Questions :

1. Should I have placed the clip under *both* layers of the doubled up area instead? My thinking was that I would rather break the seal between top and bottom layer of the SAME shingle as opposed to breaking seal between two *separate* shingles and potentially giving water access to nails.
2. In certain cases the double up “flap” section was quite narrow and the clip essentially broke adhesive for entire width between top/double up layers section. Clip is holding but that small section is flappy. Is it a big deal or could water potential travel up somehow? Or does it not matter since there’s no way for water to travel between layer of same shingle? I don’t understand the construction of a dimensional shingle well enough to forge my own opinion.
3. If 2. is indeed a problem, should I attempt to glue it back down? If yes, with what product?

If it matters. I live in the mountains with heavy snowy winter. Roof is about 15 years old. It’s currently 42°F out.

[image]

https://imgur.com/gallery/1w2Ik8e

Comment: the area of interest takes up about 5% of the picture ... please add a clear, in-focus, closeup picture of the clip on the shingle